# Is there a generic way to determine if a row can be deleted, i.e. doesn't have child rows?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Is there a generic way to determine whether a row in table `parent` has rows in "child" tables that are referencing it through their foreign keys? I want to be able to tell ahead of time if it can be deleted, i.e. I don't want to try to delete and then catch the exception if it fails.

E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
  id int unsigned primary key
);
CREATE TABLE child_1 (
  id int unsigned primary key, 
  parent_id int unsigned, 
  CONSTRAINT child_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
...
CREATE TABLE child_n (...);

INSERT INTO parent(id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO child_1(id, parent_id) VALUES (1, 1);
DELETE FROM parent WHERE id = 1;
```

In this case we get:

> ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (`mydb`.`child_1`, CONSTRAINT `child_fk1` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `parent` (`id`))

To be clear:

- I don't know what the child tables are called.
- I don't want to disable foreign key checks and delete the row regardless.
- I don't want to do a cascading delete.
- I don't want to "soft-delete" the row by adding a `deleted boolean` column and set this to "true".
- I want to find out if it's possible to delete this one row without deleting the children.

I'm thinking I can run a query I against the `information_schema` to find what the referencing child tables are. I guess that could be a recursive CTE? And then interrogate these tables in turn to find out whether they reference the particular row in the parent table that I want to delete. And potentially that can all be wrapped up into a nice stored procedure. Will that work?

Or is there some other/better way to do this?

Comment: You could a query against the information_schema to generate a bunch of parent/child table joins.

Comment: The solution via information_schema will be too complex. The solution with delete in a transaction attempt, constraint violation check, and unconditional rollback is more-more simple.

Comment: Hi @Akina - That is a pretty good idea, I would at least upvote that solution if you wrote it up as an answer. Note that I don't want to do a cascading delete, though. If there are rows in tables with foreign keys defined as `ON DELETE CASCADE` then these would not be detected with the 'transaction, delete, detect violation, rollback' solution. Unless there is a way to detect that more than one row gets deleted?